# if input text value larger than data from database, show alert

Tags: javascript

I'm getting stuck how to limit "max" value for input text by data from database.

I have a form like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="transaksiQty" id="transaksiQty"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
```

And i have a data from database called as **item_qty**. I want this input text rejects if has a larger value than **item_qty** and show alert.

Please advice,
Thanks

Comment: What server side code/framework are you using? You need to check the database value and then either write out an 'alert' or the input itself depending on value.

Comment: i'm using codeigniter...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple and easy way to limit the fields data by trimming or removing it with an alert only once on load of the page:

This example is simple and powerful using MagJS

HTML:

```
<div id="validate">
 <label>Name:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="transaksiQty" id="transaksiQty" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" value="datafromserver" />
 <hr/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var props = {
  limit: 10
}

mag.module("validate", {

  view: function(state, props) {

    state.input = {

      _config: function(node, isNew) {

        // runs only onload initially
        if (isNew && node.value.length > props.limit) {
          alert('data is larger than the limit of: ' + props.limit)

          //trim size based on limit or simply remove it ?

          // TO remove
          //node.value = '';

          //TO trim based on limit
          node.value = node.value.substr(0, props.limit)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, props)
```

Here is the link to the working example: http://jsbin.com/yuromoviko/1/edit?html,js,output

Hope that helps!

Comment: hai, thanks for your advice...
but what kind of JS are you use to run this code? because my firebug can't defined mag.module

Comment: Hi, you're very welcome! That is from a new JS library called MagJS: https://github.com/magnumjs/mag.js  - Check out this JSbin to see it working http://jsbin.com/yuromoviko/1/edit?html,js,output